# Browser tab or application switch?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to differentiate between these browser events?

- the user has clicked on another tab in the same browser, hiding my tab which now should be paused.
- they have switched to another application. My tab may still be visible, in which case it should stay running.

AFAICS, identical blur/focus DOM events are raised in each scenario, so they are no help to me.

To put it another way, is it possible to determine if a tab is actually displayed to the user?

(btw if it makes any difference, I don't need this to work in IE or any other non WebGL browser.)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events `focus` and `blur` on `window` to make it work.

Here's the sample

```
$(window).focus(function() {
   //play
});

$(window).blur(function() {
   //pause
});
```

Comment: cheers, but as I noted in the question, the events are *identical* in these two situations.  They can not help me decide between them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window none of them supports your requirement. but any workaround specific to browser might be there. and even any WebGL browser uses the standard browser event handling mechanism.

Comment: Indeed.  I suspect if there is a way, it will be a hack which does not involve browser events.